# Printing radio button value in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print the selected radio button value on a new page - my code looks as follows

```
function printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applicationsForUser){

    ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <?php   
    foreach ($applicationsForUser as $app) {    
        $name = $app->getName();
        $appId = $app->getApplicationId();
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="appNames" value="<?php $appId ?>"> <?php echo $name ?> <br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submitRadio" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    <?php
}



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitRadio'])){
    $selected_radio = $_POST['appNames'];
    echo "1234";
}else{
    echo "is not";
}

?>
```

If i print explicit values like 1234 it prints without an issue- however printing `$selected_radio` does not - why would this variable be empty?

Thanks

Comment: It's empty if it has no value or if the radio is not checked when the form is submitted (in which case it is actually `!isset($_POST['appNames'])`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to echo the value in the radio button tag

This should be

```
<input type="radio" name="appNames" value="<?php echo $appId ?>"> <?php echo $name ?>
```

Comment: perfect - will accept as soon as i can - however one question, why do i need to echo it - i come from a java background and see echo as a print so what difference does echo make here?

Comment: actually, php code is always executed at the server side, and will return the output in html, which will be rendered to your browser. In your case you was just accessing the variable, doing nothing with it, so your tag was coming with no value. when you echo the value of your php variable, it will come up with the value set in your input tag.